# Syntax Error on mySql stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my, code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_Next_Processing_Video`
(   
    OUT out_IDVideo                   INT ,
    OUT out_YoutubeIDVideo          VARCHAR(15) 
)

BEGIN

    SELECT  NP.IDVideo INTO out_IDVideo
    FROM    next_processing AS NP
  Limit 1

    UPDATE TABLE    Video AS V 
    SET     V.SchedulingFlag = TRUE
    WHERE   IDVideo = out_IDVideo

END
```

I don't understand where is the error??

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: what is the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Errors:

- you didn't terminate the first `SELECT` statement
- there was a `TABLE` after your `UPDATE` keyword.

fixed code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_Next_Processing_Video`
(   
    OUT out_IDVideo                   INT ,
    OUT out_YoutubeIDVideo          VARCHAR(15) 
)

BEGIN

    SELECT  NP.IDVideo INTO out_IDVideo
    FROM    next_processing AS NP
    Limit 1; 

    UPDATE  Video AS V 
    SET     V.SchedulingFlag = TRUE
    WHERE   IDVideo = out_IDVideo;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

alternatively, you can use `SET` to assign the value on the variable.

```
    SET out_IDVideo = (SELECT   NP.IDVideo 
                        FROM    next_processing AS NP
                        Limit 1);
```

Comment: you're welcome `:D` I'm wondering what this variable `out_YoutubeIDVideo` for. hehe